# Azure Active Directory does not logout the user properly?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, botframework

What is the logout URL for the Azure Active Directory connection. My redirect URL is `https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect`. I used Microsoft bot framework node.js version 4 to make the connection. In my bot when I type logout it just saying 'you have been signed out'.But behind the scenes it was not clearing the user's session data. So next time when I try to login with different account it is not allowing because it does not logout properly.

I referred to many Microsoft documents to search my logout url to logout the user properly. But even after a long time I cannot able to find it.

My logout code in node.js botbuilder version4

```
let botAdapter : BotFrameworkAdapter =<BotFrameworkAdapter>context.adapter;
await botAdapter.signOutUser(context, connection);
await context.sendActivity('You have been signed out.');
```

> My redirect or reply URL -
>   https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect

I searched many stackoverflow questions where everyone suggest to use the below urls

> https://login.windows.net/{tenantid or
>   "common"}/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={URL}
>
> https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={1}

But it is not working for me. It may because I have used token.botframework which is different from login.microsoftonline.com.

Any one please help what may be a correct logout url for my redirect url.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you finding a place to put a logout URL?

Comment: @Kyle Delaney In azure select azure active directory (on left side panel) -> App Registrations(on left side panel) -> select our application -> Authentication (on left side panel) -> Under Advanced settings -> there is text field called Logout URL.

Comment: You don't need to use that for bot authentication. What channel are you using?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I am using Microsoft Teams

Comment: There have been some recent auth issues on our servers and we've been actively fixing things over the past week. It may be a good idea to wait a few days to see if the issue persists.

Comment: @KyleDelaney. Thanks for your response. I can wait for a couple of day to check whether the issue persists.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Is this problem occurs due to problems in azure.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Does the issue is fixed? Still facing same issue.

Comment: Have you set the `validDomains` in your app manifest?

Comment: @KyleDelaney yes, I had given valid domain as token.botframework. Even it is not working in bot Emulator also.

Comment: @KyleDelaney actually when I logged in azure with azure AD the token will be generated then I never expire that token. While creating the application I said to token to never expire. May be is this due to token expire problem.

Comment: @KyleDelaney I am using multitenant account, when I test in skype channel with azure initially it asks me list of microsoft account to login, When I logged in from the next time it is not showing the accounts to login. It directly takes the previous logged in account.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Any help please. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of the Node authentication sample? https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/18.bot-authentication

Comment: @KyleDelaney yes tried many times, but same response. I think the problem is with azure connections.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding what it means to log out. Are you expecting the dialog stack to be cleared or the conversation history to be erased perhaps? Please edit your question to explain what's happening when you log out and what you expect to happen.

Comment: Goo to hear. Would you like to post your fix as an answer to this question so you can mark it as accepted?

Comment: @Prakash what was the solution please?